# Playing an mp3 (from my phone) through my internet radio

Tags: wi-fi, streaming, mp3

On my old Samsung Galaxy Ace running Android 2.3.6 or so, there was a Samsung system app called "allshare". I really really loved this app. It was simple and unpretentious, and it did the following amazing thing: when I was in my kitchen, with my phone connected to my home wireless network, and my internet radio was also in my kitchen, also connected to my home wireless network, I could play an mp3 on my phone and direct the output to the internet radio. It was simple and it worked, and I used it a lot.

Woo hoo! I now have a sparkling brand new HTC one mini, running Android 4.something large. I went straight to google play to download my allshare. But I can only find "Samsung Link" (formerly Allshare Play, which might well have been the app I was using) and it is incompatible with all my devices (possibly for the reason that they are not samsung devices).

I want my functionality back! I am assuming that if Samsung can get this to work on an old 2.3.6 phone, it must be possible to get my HTC one mini doing it, right?

Comment: You could take a look at [BubbleUPnP](http://www.appbrain.com/app/bubbleupnp-upnp-dlna/com.bubblesoft.android.bubbleupnp). Not exaclty the same as AllShare, but might help you out.

Comment: @Izzy: this has exactly the functionality I was looking for. Many thanks! If you want to leave your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Glad it solved your issue! As requested, I made it an answer with some more details. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*AllShare* is a Samsung specific product, which might not be available to devices of different brands. However, as it's basically a DLNA server/client app, you might want to take a look at some of the many alternatives available. A very good choice would be [BubbleUPnP](http://www.appbrain.com/app/bubbleupnp-upnp-dlna/com.bubblesoft.android.bubbleupnp), which acts both as server and client (so you can stream from your device to other DLNA/UPnP clients as well as the other way around):

> BubbleUPnP is a full featured UPnP/DLNA Control Point, UPnP Media Renderer and UPnP Media Server. Play easily your music, videos and images on your phone and devices on your network (DLNA TVs, XBMC, WMP, ...), from your external UPnP Media Servers. Play your phone/tablet media to those devices.
>   Browse and play your local phone/tablet and cloud media from other devices (PS3, ...).
>
> BubbleUPnP can also be used as a standalone music player, even without any network connection.